# SharePoint 2016 compatibility

Tags: 2013, migration, 2016, api

Does anyone know the link to API or document for API in SharePoint 2016? We are currently using '.Net client API' for SharePoint 2013 and want to check if the methods used from it will still be compatible for SharePoint 2016.
Thank you

Comment: This can help https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679

Comment: Thank you for the link. The link points to installation of 'SharePoint Server 2016 Client Components SDK'. However, I am not able to find the documentation of API for the methods available, e.g. '.Net client API'.